# Image placement within a set page-wrap?

Tags: html, css, image

I was wondering if it is possible to set up the page-wrap in a way so that the width is the maximum limitation to how the images and text boxes can float and left/right/top/bottom commands. below is an image that clarifies my question because my coding vocabulary is very limited at the moment: [image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh129L5b/19/

```
#container {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    height: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 48em;
}

#red {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 70%;
}

#blu {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 40%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
```

or, if you want use *position* property instead of *float*:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh129L5b/28/

```
#container {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    height: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 48em;
    position: relative;
}

#wrapper > div {
    position: absolute;
}

#red {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    bottom: 20%;
}

#blu {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    top: 40%;
    right: 5%;
}
```

Comment: Hi @KaMZaTa, thank you for your comment. However, I'm wondering if it is possible to work with an absolute image placement. For example, bottom:0 and right:0; for an image that is within a 80% wide and 100% high page-wrapper... I am not really looking for a solution that consists of the use of: float:right/left.